# Why was Bonnie pregnant for seven years (seasons) on Family Guy?

Tags: family-guy

I am just curious to know why Bonnie Swanson, wife of Joe Swanson, was kept pregnant until the seventh season.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because it's cartoons — Stewie is still a baby, too. Generally, cartoons are not too happy about altering the state of the show by letting big things happen.

Cartoons are for a lot of people not shows they follow consistently, rather they just watch a few episodes once in a while in no particular order. To that end, if the scenario changed in every episode (like it does with more continious story-telling tv shows like Breaking Bad), it would confuse the audience.

Imagine watching just a few random episodes of Breaking Bad: you'd have no idea what was going on. That's great for such a dramatic show, but not the norm in comedies and cartoons.

Comment: Why would an animated series have inherently less loyal viewers? If I like a TV show I keep watching it, whether the characters are drawn or played by humans doesn't matter to me. - The _[serial vs procedural](http://seriable.com/serialized-vs-procedural-television-series/)_ issue exists for _live action_ shows as well. And there are animated shows that are serialized, e.g. [Young Justice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Justice_(TV_series)), which I watched every episode of.

Comment: @Oliver_C This might sound condescending, but I can assure you it's not: From your profile I can see that you're 36 and you say you've watched every episode of a TV show produced for Cartoon Network (a children's channel). I know there are exceptions, and I feel like it's fair to say that you're not the avenrage viewer that I'm describing in my answer. Notice I say "a lot of people", not "all people". Besides, this is just what I gather from my understanding of the viewers of shows such as Simpsons, Family Guy, American Dad, South Park, etc.

Comment: [According to](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/09/13/magazine/13FOB-Q4-t.html?_r=3&) __Seth MacFarlane__ the target audience for _Family Guy_ is `Men, 18 to 34`. Just because a show is animated doesn't mean it's only for kids, at least not anymore. Some of todays "cartoons" are actually rather sophisticated.

Comment: I'm not talking about Family Guy, but Young Justice. I know Family Guy is an adult show.

Comment: To quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Justice_(TV_series)#Reception_and_legacy): `Young Justice has garnered critical acclaim for its originality as well as its mature and complex storyline` (I only mentioned this series because it's an example of a _serialized_ animated show) - As I said earlier, the _serial vs procedural_ problem, which seems to be the essence of your answer, applies to both, _animated_ and _live action_ shows. You seem to say that animated shows have to be procedurals because they have less viewer loyalty. I don't understand why you think that's the case?

Comment: My personal experience is that people don't want shows such as Family Guy as consistently as they do with other shows. I don't know what else to say. Your experiences may differ (and that's fine), but my answer just reflects my own experience. :)

Comment: Personal experience is usually fine here, but when you wrote `for a lot of people` I just wondered where you got that from, e.g. an article or documentary, because to me it doesn't make sense to say: _"I really like show X, but because it's animated I'm not interested in watching every episode"_.

Comment: I will say not cartoons but Comedy shows kept then non-serialize to attract part-time viewers. But it is also an assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Family Guy, American Dad and shows like that are semi non-linear. They reference past seasons and so time does go on in their worlds, but they aren't that linear that they define age of characters.